# `expect_error` inside `test_that` does not work

Tags: r, testthat

If I run following, behavior is expected. Nothing is returned

```
expect_error(expect_true(FALSE))
```

When I run the same code, but wrapped inside `test_that`

```
test_that("expect_error should not fail",{
        expect_error(expect_true(FALSE))
})

Error: Test failed: 'expect_error should not fail'
* Not expected: FALSE isn't true.
* Not expected: expect_true(FALSE) code did not generate an error.
```

Output is weird, means that `expect_true(FALSE)` doesn't generate error when folded within `test_that`.

How can I put `expect_error` inside `test_that`?

**UPDATE**

I used `testthat` for code assertion. There is package [`assertthat`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertthat/index.html) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what `expect_error` is meant to do. It is supposed to catch errors in user code, not errors in tests.

`expect_that` will generate an error, but this error will be handled inside `test_that` *before* `expect_error` will get a chance to treat it.

Don’t wrap `expect_*` calls inside `expect_error`. Using `expect_error` directly works:

```
test_that('expect_error catches error conditions', {
    expect_error(stop('foo'))
})
```

The inconsistency in behaviour comes from the fact that `test_that` will catch errors generated by `expect_*` instead of letting them propagate normally.

Comment: It makes no sense. Try that: `expect_error(expect_true(FALSE))` no problems. `expect_error(expect_true(TRUE))` gives `Error: expect_true(TRUE) code did not generate an error`. That means that `expect_true(FALSE)` generates error and it is expected.

Comment: @CronAcronis Actually, scratch that. I’m changing my answer, there’s a mistake.

Comment: @CronAcronis See if this makes more sense to you.

Comment: I see. Is there anyway how I can expect error from `expect_*` family of functions? I do not use `stop`, expecting function just to fail, if some conditions met.

Comment: @CronAcronis Well the thing is that the `expect_that` functions are supposed to be used in unit tests only, not in library code. I don’t think there’s a good way around this behaviour, as it’s generally not possible to distinguish whether the `expect_that` is supposed to belong to the unit test or the library. I’m assuming you’re using `expect_that` for assertions in your code. Unfortunately it’s not intended for this usage. Use the `assertthat` package instead.